# EKS pod stuck in "Pending" state in Fargate deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

So I created an EKS cluster for Fargate with the following manifest, and it created ok. I want to run applications in Fargate, not in EC2 worker nodes, so I didn't create node groups (correct?).

```
$ eksctl create -f cluster.yaml
cluster.yaml
------------
metadata:
  name: sandbox
  region: us-east-1
  version: "1.18"

fargateProfiles:
  - name: fp-default
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "default" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: default
      # All workloads in the "kube-system" Kubernetes namespace will be
      # scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: kube-system
  - name: fp-sandbox
    selectors:
      # All workloads in the "sandbox" Kubernetes namespace matching the
      # following label selectors will be scheduled onto Fargate:
      - namespace: sandbox
        labels:
          env: sandbox
          checks: passed

$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                     STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
fargate-ip-192-168-100-23.ec2.internal   Ready    <none>   3h2m   v1.18.8-eks-7c9bda
fargate-ip-192-168-67-135.ec2.internal   Ready    <none>   3h2m   v1.18.8-eks-7c9bda
```

Then I created a namespace

```
$ kubectl create namespace sandbox
```

Now I create a deployment in the `sandbox` namespace to match the namespace in my `fp-sandbox` Fargate profile, and is stuck in `Pending` state

```
$ kubectl create deploy hello-world-node --image=redacted.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world-node:latest --namespace=sandbox
$ kubectl get po -n sandbox
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-world-node-544748b68b-4bghr   0/1     Pending   0          18m

$ kubectl describe pod hello-world-node-544748b68b-4bghr -n sandbox
....
Events:
Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
----     ------            ----                ----               -------
Warning  FailedScheduling  12s (x15 over 19m)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 Too many pods.
```

Why does it say `0/2 nodes are available`? What am I missing? Remember I want to run the application in Fargate, not in EC2 worker nodes.

NOTE: I can run the container locally. It's just a simple NodeJS app that echoes "Hello World."

**UPDATE**: I added a `manageNodeGroups` to my cluster, and the pod came up. However, why so? Why didn't the pods run in Fargate, without the node group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per help/advise from Meir (again, lol), I used a deployment manifest instead, and it worked. Here's it is

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-node
  namespace: sandbox
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world-node
      env: sandbox
      checks: passed
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world-node
        env: sandbox
        checks: passed
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world-node
          image: redacted.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world-node:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

Then apply it with

```
$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
$ kubectl get po -n sandbox
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-world-node-58f86974c4-7tnzb   1/1     Running   0          3m58s
```

Answer (score 1):

@Chris, hi again :)

In your YAML file

```yaml
      # All workloads in the "sandbox" Kubernetes namespace matching the
      # following label selectors will be scheduled onto Fargate:
```

There's an `AND` condition between the two sentences above, so your pods should be assigned with `env=sandbox` and `checks=passed` labels.

A quick fix

```sh
kubectl --namespace sandbox label pods --all env=sandbox
kubectl --namespace sandbox label pods --all checks=passed
```

A better way to fix it is by writing a deployment.yaml file and add the labels in the relevant place.

### References

- [Kubernetes API Label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#label)
- [Labels and Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/)
- [nginx deployment.yaml example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml)

Comment: LOL Meir. Thanks again. I'm slowly but surely getting it. I did that but still pods not running. My pods now have the following labels `app=hello-world-node,checks=passed,env=sandbox,pod-template-hash=544748b68b`

Comment: Can you try the same thing but with a deployment.yaml file? Let's see if it works. Also, see [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/), this might help with setting the labels and selectorLabels

Comment: I'll try a deployment. I just like running long-hand commands first to understand what goes on under the hood.